# Replace multiple characters with multiple replacers

Tags: php, regex

I have many calls like this throughout the code, escaping any backticks on the columns of a row.

```
htmlentities(str_replace("`", "``", $row['column']), ENT_QUOTES);
```

I made an addition, requiring the column to replace a `#`width `##`. Since most of these calls happen inline an output, I would like to have a solution in a single line.

I was thinking conditional regex (preg_replace_callback), but is this the best way to achieve that? So what I need is:
replace backticks with 2 backticks, and replace hashes with 2 hashes. (This is for escaping purposes).

Comment: Remember that you can *single line* everything by making a function do the work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) supports array parameters:

```
// translation map:
$map = [
    '`' => '``',
    '#' => '##'
];

// what to replace:
$from = array_keys($map);

// replace by what:
$to   = array_values($map);

echo htmlentities(str_replace($from, $to, $row['column']), ENT_QUOTES);
```

In rare cases, that requires you to minify your code, you may try to use that:

```
echo htmlentities(str_replace([ '`', '#' ], [ '``', '##' ], $row['column']), ENT_QUOTES));
//                            ^             ^
//                        from what     by what
```

Comment: he said in single row :p

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I believe it would be not readable, so I *strongly* suggest to write readable code.

Comment: Sometimes there comes situation you need just a single row, not wasting things for unreadable 'readable'

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili sometimes. However, it might be "good" to think about future readers not to cry by blood, by "deminifying" source codes or templates.

Comment: While I agree, that this would be the proper way of making readable code, it's not applicable with the code I have. There are a lot of those calls throughout the code, and I just needed a replacement-string for my IDE.

Comment: C'mon I know that thing, and always try and do that.

Comment: @Johannes truly agree

Comment: @Johannes Then use Justinas answer.

Comment: @HAL9000 why Justinas? It's not noted that he's using php 5.4 or higher where `[]` style arrays will not work. And I answer before. You are not right man

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili It's not noted that OP's using `php 5.3 or lower where` also.

Comment: So `array()` will work in any case but `[]` will not :p

Comment: C'mon don't take it so much personal, you just don't like me :p

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [documentation of `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-examples), you can use can use arrays:

```
str_replace(["`", "#"], ["``", "##"], $row['column']);
```

Answer (score 3):

if someone would prefer to use a regular expression:

```
preg_replace("/`|#/", "$0$0")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, just use arrays as params for `str_replace`

```
htmlentities(str_replace(array("`","#"), array("``","##"), $row['column']), ENT_QUOTES);
```